# Graphical novel/comic book about a society of diesel punk animals

Tags: story-identification, comics, animals

I'm looking for a book I remember from when I was a kid (20-25 years ago in Australia), I think it was about a dieselpunk society of animals. At least I think it was dieselpunk, as I remember that most had souped up bikes or cars, or maybe even were implanted/merged with the tech.

I remember a dark and gritty city, possibly with different gangs on the streets.

I think that the physical size of the book was a large format, like the size of Asterix or Tin Tin. It was also in color, and I think it was in English since I did borrow it and I didn't tend to borrow books in a language that I wasn't able to read.

Unfortunately I'm not able to remember any plot points or characters from so long ago, but I do remember that some of the animals were large ones like rhinos and elephants.

Comment: Apart from the animal part, this sounds a lot like *Kar War* by French-Brazilian artist Alain Voss. Some of the characters, however, are inhuman and somewhat animalistic. You can see pages from that story (and others) here: https://www.humano.com/blog/Le-Blog-de-Jerry-Frissen/tag/Alain-Voss/1

Comment: Unfortunately it's been so long that I'm not able to remember any plot points or characters. All I can remember is that some of the animals that featured were large ones like rhinos and elephants.

And the Kar War looks cool, but is not the one I was looking for. Thanks anyway though :)

Comment: When were you a kid? Do you know what language it was in? Where did you grow up? Was it in color or black and white?

Comment: I edited my question to add this info.